# How to handle Wikipedia Named Entities that have the same Category name

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I was trying to extract all US companies so I ran the following query

```
PREFIX cat: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:> 
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?page ?subcat  WHERE { ?subcat skos:broader* cat:Companies_of_the_United_States_by_industry . 
?page dcterms:subject ?subcat . 
?page  rdfs:label ?pageName. 
}
```

This is a snapshot of the results
[image]

Amgen and Pfizer are both companies as well as Category, so I end up collecting everything under Pfizer and Amgen (people, product). I found out that these entries belong to wikipedia category called Category:Wikipedia_categories_named_after_companies_of_the_United_States or Category:Wikipedia_categories_named_after_pharmaceutical_companies_of_the_United_States. So I tried to filter these categories so I did this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?page ?subcat  WHERE { ?subcat skos:broader* cat:Companies_of_the_United_States_by_industry . 
?page dcterms:subject ?subcat . 
?page  rdfs:label ?pageName. 
FILTER( !regex(?subcat,"Wikipedia_categories_named_after_pharmaceutical_companies_of_the_United_States")) }
```

But no luck, they are still there. Any idea how to avoid this problem?

Comment: The problem isn't that that they have the same name., though. :Pfizer and Category:Pfizer are different URIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem doesn't have anything to do with them having the same name.  Wikipedia categories don't form a type hierarchy, so it doesn't make sense to treat them like one.  The reason you see the results that you're seeing is that there's a [category Pfizer](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category%3aPfizer), and that its broader values include the company listings, but is also the dcterms:subject of dbpedia:Alprazolam, dbpedia:Cetirizine, etc.  It doesn't make sense as a type hierarchy, but it is fine for organizing article topics.   If you only want companies back, just ask for things that are companies:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?page ?subcat  WHERE {
  ?subcat skos:broader* category:Companies_of_the_United_States_by_industry . 
  ?page dcterms:subject ?subcat . 
  ?page rdfs:label ?pageName. 
  ?page a dbpedia-owl:Company
}
```

We can clean that up a bit, though.  You're not using ?label, so we can remove it.  We can use some of the shorter syntaxes to make things a little bit cleaner.  We can also note that "Companies … by industry" has a skos:broader value "Companies of the United States" which makes the intent of the query a bit clearer.

```sql
select distinct ?company ?subcategory  where {
  ?company dcterms:subject ?subcategory ;
           a dbpedia-owl:Company .
  ?subcategory skos:broader* category:Companies_of_the_United_States . 
}
limit 1000
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20select%20distinct%20%3Fcompany%20%3Fsubcategory%20%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcompany%20dcterms%3Asubject%20%3Fsubcategory%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACompany%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fsubcategory%20skos%3Abroader%2a%20category%3ACompanies_of_the_United_States%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20limit%201000&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

As a final note, the category hierarchy doesn't necessarily mean that each company has a single path to the top category.  That is, you could get some company listed multiple times, e.g.:

```
company   subcategory
------------------------------------
companyX  Textile_Companies
companyX  Companies_in_New_Hampshire
```

Unless you need the listing of subcategories, you might consider eliminating it from the query, in which case you can simply have (using property paths):

```sql
select distinct ?company where {
  ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
           dcterms:subject/skos:broader* category:Companies_of_the_United_States .
}
limit 1000
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fcompany%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcompany%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACompany%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dcterms%3Asubject%2Fskos%3Abroader%2a%20category%3ACompanies_of_the_United_States%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%201000&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)